# Parsing string to numbers separated by token in angular

Tags: angular

I have one value that is like this

```
dealerGoogelMapLatLong: string = '-15.403505, 28.321922';
```

I need from that value to get like this

```
lat: number = -15.403505;
lng: number = 28.321922;
```

That i can use later for displaying google maps, how to split this to two values, txanks

Comment: Did you try with `split(',')`

Comment: Can you please write complete answer

Comment: BTW are you sure you have value like that because you cannot have number with that type in `typescript`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the type of your raw value is `string`, as `-15.403505, 28.321922` isnt a valid number.

You could try with the following:

```
const val:string = "-15.403505, 28.321922";
const splitted: string[] = val.split(',');

const first:number = Number.parseFloat(splitted[0]); 
// Optional parse to float if required. Otherwise handle as string.
const second:number = Number.parseFloat(splitted[1]);

console.log(`First is ${first}. Second is ${second}`);
```